# A question on the continuity of a functional

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $u \in L^{p}(\Omega)$, $\Omega$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $q+1<p$ and $p \geq 2$. Is the functional defined by $v\mapsto\int_{\Omega}u^qv$ continuous over $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$?.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply Holder's inequality: Your conditions imply that $qp'<p$, where $p'=p/(p-1)$, so that
$$
\left| \int_\Omega u^q v \right| \leq \| u^q\|_{p'} \| v\|_p =\| u\|_{qp'}^{q} \| v\|_p\leq C\| u\|_p^{q}\| v\|_p.
$$

Comment: Hi Jose...thanks for the reply...Will it not be $||u^{q}||_{p^{'}}=||u||^{q}_{qp^{'}}$?...

Comment: @Alexander: Yep, thanks.